# How will transformer efficiency change if the transformer is connected backwards?

Tags: transformer, efficiency

Suppose I have a transformer designed to convert 220 volts into 5 volts and when it works in this mode being 95% loaded its efficiency is 97%. Now I connect the secondary winding to a 5 volts power source and connect appropriate 220 volts load to the primary so that the transformer converts 5 volts into 220 volts and is 95% loaded.

How will the transformer efficiency change? Will it remain 97%?

Comment: Where did you find a 95% efficient transformer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Efficiency depends on frequency, current and source & load impedance. If you use the same on each winding, it is reversible and similar efficiency can be expected.